# Angular. Class as method of other class

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm beginner in Angular2 and get some problem. I've created a component **info**. In the **info.component.ts** I initialize objects like this:

```
import { Comm } from '../shared/comments';
...
const VASACOM: Comm = {
  name: 'Vasa',
  id: 122,
  comments: [
    {
     rating: 5,
     comment: "Some commment",
     date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
    },
   {
    rating: 4,
    comment: "Other comment",
    date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
   }
  ]
};
```

The class Comm in **comments.ts**:

```
export class Comm {
 name: string;
 id: number;
 comments: Comment[];
 constructor(name:string,id:number,comments:Comment[]){
   this.name = name;
   this.id = id;
   this.comments = comments;
 }
}

export class Comment {
   rating: number;
   comment: string;
   date: string;
}
```

And I get an error:

> error TS2322: Object literal may only specify know properties, and 'comments' does not exist in type 'Comm'

What did I do wrong?

p.s. I understand that we can create 2 objects separately, one of them Comm class, other Comment, but I want to do that in one object.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I would use `interface` instead of `class` when you just want to specify object literals.

Comment: Also, you're probably not shwing us your actual code: the type `stirng` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Actual cod just have more variables,but the concept is the same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a requirement for code-related questions.

Comment: you are missing constructor in Comment class. Add one like you have added for comm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the constructor for your Comm class and Comments class.

```
export class Comm {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public id: number,
    public comments: Comment[]
  ){}
}

export class Comment {
   constructor(
     public rating: number,
     public comment: string,
     public date: string
   ){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the server. I think this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can make those classes as an interface

```
export interface Comm {
 name: stirng;
 id: number;
 comments: Comment[];
}

export interface Comment {
   rating: number;
   comment: string;
   date: string;
}
```

and with the help of service, you can just get the value like:

```
@Injectable()
export class Items {
  getAll(): Comm[] {
    return VASACOM;
  }
```

and it should be something like

```
const VASACOM: Comm = [{
  name: 'Vasa',
  id: 122,
  comments: [
    {
     rating: 5,
     comment: "Some commment",
     date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
    },
   {
    rating: 4,
    comment: "Other comment",
    date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
   }
  ]
}];
```